# Best method for creating a pure HTML5 + CSS3 animated "sonar wave" icon.

Tags: html, animation, css, css-transitions

I've created the following animated icon here:

http://jsfiddle.net/KphgD/9

Does anyone have any experience designing a comparable icon or have any suggestions on making this better, more "realistic"?

I would be open to using javascript perhaps to increment the animations so that each curve moves outward at an increasing rate.

Comment: What do you mean by "realistic"?

Comment: You'd have a lot more control of what you were doing using [`SVG`](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/svg/info)

Comment: Wex, would you say that SVG is as equally supported as CSS3 animations?

Comment: By realistic i mean what a satellite dish looks like when it gives off all those waves :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Status Update:**

***Firefox v14.0.1 fails to render this Answer (and jsFiddle's in messages) correctly. Use Firefox version prior to v14.0.1 or stable v15.0***

---

Looking at your jsFiddle, I can see that Chrome is ***enlarging*** the original font **without** resizing it.

My goal was to include CSS only method to scale the Font Size, but I could not do that in pure CSS. Perhaps **somebody else** can.

My method then took a different approach. That said, I changed all the font sizes in your example so they are really large. Then I placed all the `span tags` in a wrapper `div` and made that really small.

The end result is a **HD Version** of your example that works well in Chrome. No more pixelated edges to see on the font.

Currently, the **CSS3 Animations** causes slowdown in stable build **Firefox v13** when 2 or more examples are on the webpage. **Chrome** does not have this problem and can display  ***all*** of them with **no** slowdown!

---

Here are my jsFiddles that includes **10** CSS3 style examples:

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/GEUvZ/) for Firefox (just 1 example is enabled).
[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/GEUvZ/1/) for Chrome (all 10 examples are enabled).

**Reminder:** The Chrome jsFiddle will cause *CPU Spike in Firefox* since Firefox chokes on CSS3 Animations that are too intensive. Perchance next Firefox update fixes that bug.

---

**Edit:** For a different **easing flavor**, you can use any **cubic-bezier**. There are many **Online Easing Generators** that will supply a preset or custom made value such as this generator [**HERE**](http://matthewlein.com/ceaser/). Just select an easing preset and hit the **Left Button** to view it. Then if you like it, copy only the **cubic-bezier** and use it like so:

```
.pulse{
    -webkit-animation: pulsate 1.600s infinite cubic-bezier(0.190, 1.000, 0.220, 1.000);
    -moz-animation: pulsate 1.600s infinite cubic-bezier(0.190, 1.000, 0.220, 1.000);
}
```

Just change the `1.600s` duration to what you your using or adjust as required.
 
Single Example: [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/GEUvZ/7/)

Comment: I used animation-delay in this example based yours: http://jsfiddle.net/GEUvZ/5/ it has a nice staggered effect

Comment: Thanks! Also using **extra** div's in "reverse" does interesting things: [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/GEUvZ/8/)

Answer (score 1):

Check this part of the animation principles
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12_basic_principles_of_animation#Follow_through_and_overlapping_action

Instead of displaying all at once, overlap some action of the individual arcs.

**Edit**

For example:
http://jsfiddle.net/efortis/KphgD/7/

```
<span class="pulse1 circ">&#9696;</span>
<span class="pulse2 circ med">&#9696;</span>
<span class="pulse3 circ small">&#9696;</span>
<span class="pulse4 circ tiny">&#9696;</span>
<span class="circ small point">&#8226;</span>

.pulse1 { -webkit-animation: pulsate 1.1s infinite ease-out; }
.pulse2 { -webkit-animation: pulsate .9s infinite ease-out; }
.pulse3 { -webkit-animation: pulsate .7s infinite ease-out; }
.pulse4 { -webkit-animation: pulsate .2s infinite ease-out; }
```

P.D. Play with the easing and duration to tune it.
​

Comment: that's great advice... but the question (as this is a programming forum) is how?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/KphgD/9/ ... -web-kit-animation-delay works very well for that concept!