# CSS3 animation, translate to position

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate, css-transforms

I have a div that I click on to drag it. Once it's on an area, it animates to its position via:

```
$("#wheel1").animate({left: "200px", top: "100px"});
```

I can also get it to animate with:

```
@-webkit-keyframes wheel1 {
    0% {
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(200px, 100px);
    }
}
```

The difference being; with jQuery it animates to 200px from the left of the document. With CSS3, it animates 200px from where you drop it (which is bad)

Is there a way to make CSS3 animate from the top left of the document, as jQuery does? I've tried changing transform-origin and a few other settings with no luck.

Comment: I'm not sure how margins will help, the jQuery way is already perfect, with CSS3, how do you translate margins?

Comment: Im not sure you're reading the problem correctly. Using left/right is fine for jQ. The jQ solution is solid and it works. I'm trying to achieve the exact same thing with CSS3 though, via CSS animation. Margins and positions cannot be used, it has to be translateX/Y

Comment: This might be a relevant link in the context of how top/left/right/bottom transformations (even in CSS not just jQuery) differ from using `translate`: [**http://www.paulirish.com/2012/why-moving-elements-with-translate-is-better-than-posabs-topleft/**](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/why-moving-elements-with-translate-is-better-than-posabs-topleft/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not an expert in CSS3 transforms, but I think `translate` is relative to the element's original position.

One way I can see to achieve what you want with CSS would be to position the element absolutely, and use a CSS3 `transition` to change its `left` and `top` properties.

Here is a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nSa9s/2/

HTML:

```
<div class="box"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.box {
    position: absolute;
    background: #ff0000;
    left: 400px;
    top: 200px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    -webkit-transition: all 1.0s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 1.0s linear;
    -o-transition: all 1.0s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 1.0s linear;    
    transition: all 1.0s linear;
}
.box.move {
    left: 200px;
    top: 100px;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.box').on('click', function() {
        $(this).addClass('move');
    });
});
```

The purpose of the JS is to add the `move` class to the element when it is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

FYI, to do this with CSS animations (not transitions as the selected answer shows), you simply need to use `left` in your keyframe instead of translate.

```
@-webkit-keyframes wheel1 {
    0% {}
    100% {
        left:200px; top: 100px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please correct me if I am wrong, but the reason why you want to use CSS3 animations is because jQuery animations is not doing what the CSS3 animations can do?

If I'm correct, then look at this jQuery plugin named [**.transit**](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/) which allow you to apply all CSS3 Animations to any selector the way it would of been applied in CSS3 format, but it's done via programmatic jQuery methods.

That plugin handles lot's of CSS3 sliding and movement requirements and any other CSS3 animations you can throw at it. The above link has examples all over the page.

If this is not want you want, realize CSS can not "detect" when an object is "dropped" into another element. There is the `:hover` pseudo trigger, but that will trigger every time **no matter what**.

Comment: I'll give it a go, thanks. The reason I am trying to use CSS3 over jQuery is because it's more efficient. I read it also passes off the effort required to the GPU rather than the CPU. I don't doubt this, as when I translated a 7000px background from one side of the screen to the other, it chugged along with jQ but moved perfectly smoothly with CSS.

Comment: Please doubt this... please see my [**SO Answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11011569/1195891) for a pure CSS Animation Sonar Wave FX. Firefox chokes while Chrome sings. That said, looking at the specific code your talking about is required for analysis to see why it's slow in jQuery.

Comment: Sorry, probably should have mentioned 'for the iPad'

Comment: Ahh, well that certainly is a game changer. I recommend that you mention the target browser/device in your SO Question. Also, if your using jQuery-mobile then that too is a different Tag from what you are showing now.