# Glowing right angle quote animation with CSS3 and/or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, css

I'm looking to make a clever animation that makes three sucessive right angle quotes like  `» » »` glow successively from left to right, then back to the left-most one again. I'm wondering if this might be a clever effect for other developers to use as well, and could be good Google-fodder.

The inspiration for this is obviously the slide-to-unlock screen on an iPhone, where the text glows in a progressive manner.

I do know about CSS3 animations with keyframes and have implemented these successfully before, but am not sure how to code in the part with the loop. I'm guessing Javascript is the answer here, with some kind of loop. I already have jQuery on the page I'm using so it wouldn't be anything extra to use jQuery functionality.

My HTML structure would be something like this:

`<span class="glowquote"><span>&raquo;</span> <span>&raquo;</span> <span>&raquo;</span></span>`

Any ideas on the best/most clever way to implement this? I realize not all browsers support CSS3 animations if they are to be used and honey badger don't care, I only need to support modern webkit and gecko implementations.

**Edit 1:** added span tags around each `&raquo;` to allow changing CSS properties individually for each right angle quote in JavaScript, as most people have done. For the guy who did the CSS3 method, not necessary!

**Edit 2:** Just for absolute clarity on what the goal is, the left-most one will glow a certain color first, using a CSS `color:green` etc. change and `transition:color linear 0.4s` etc, then the next one will do the same right after with maybe a short delay.

**Edit 3:** For further clarification, the exact animation I'm looking for looks like this, though in the example they've used a *VERY* hack-ish method that I don't think will work for a lot of people. I'm wondering if we are just coming up against the limitations of javascript/css3 or if there is more refinement possible. Link: http://css-tricks.com/examples/SlideToUnlock/

---

**FINAL EDIT WITH SOLUTION SUMMARY:** I decided to go with the pure CSS3 option but there are many valid options presented here that are all worthy of your time. I wish StackOverflow would allow for more than one correct answer. For anyone coming to this question from Google or elsewhere, make sure to browse the whole question to choose what may work the best for you! I figured that since this is mostly just for fun, I would feel okay leaving the Firefox & IE guys out in the dark. You can see what my final implemention was here: http://ezrahub.com/board/ at the top of the page, where it is used to expand the posting form. One quirk is that if you change the text size, you will also have to change the property `background-size` in your CSS stylesheet. I used `background-size: 120px 50%;` for mine, and if you play around with it you can see how the effect changes.

Hope everyone has fun with this and enjoy using it on your creations! Shout out to autistic moderators such as @JaredFarrish. (Why so mad?)

Comment: **Edit 2:** I guess I never thought about it this way, but a bit different Googling yielded this: http://css-tricks.com/slide-to-unlock/

Clever?

Comment: Yeah, that backlit spotlighting effect is possible with advanced CSS3, but it would take some clever creativity to get it tuned in. http://threejs.org could do it, of course, and webgl is supported in the browsers you mentioned. Just a thought. `;)`

Comment: You could replace the whole thing with an animated gif...

Comment: @nnnnnn yeah, but that wouldn't be any fun, would it?

I guess in the end you've got to sacrifice somewhere. Those little circley loading wheel things use .gifs as well, no fancy tricks with CSS/Javascript there.

Comment: @nnnnnn - In the immortal words of The Dude, "You must be a golfer".

Comment: @wnajar, Please see my [**SO Answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11011569/1195891) that describes how to animate a Sonar symbol. You can mod that so it's half a Sonar, and use double arrows instead. Most recent [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/GEUvZ/7/) example and [**another one**](http://jsfiddle.net/GEUvZ/8/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the fun of it, here is a method using pure css. It has *very* limited support for browsers.

```
.glowquote {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, black 0%, green 40%, green 60%, black 100%);
    background-size: auto 50%;

    padding: 0 100px;

    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;

    -webkit-animation: gradient-animation infinite 1s linear;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/grc4/uF8H2/3/

**Edit:** The jsfiddle now partly works in firefox. The gradient animation works correctly, and the only thing that does't work is the text clipping ([`-moz-background-clip:text` doesn't exist](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-background-clip)). This could be solved by using an image mask over the top of the background.

Comment: The OP mentioned that Gecko support is also relevant; can it be ported to Gecko (Firefox)?

Comment: Wow, very slick! That has the animation that is desired AND is pure CSS. I didn't even think that would be possible...

I guess we have a bunch of good answers here, none of them are "right" so to speak it's just cool to see some clever ways to do it. Nobody has done exactly the same method but they all work!

Awesome!


**Edit:** Yes, support for Gecko is very relevant as about 95% of all users will be on some flavor of Chrome or Firefox, but if the Firefox guys get left out then so be it. This method looks a lot flashier, but does have the problem of not really working with Gecko. :(

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't work on Firefox. You get a static gradient and black arrows, and nothing happens.

Comment: @JaredFarrish feels bad that it doesn't work on Firefox.... I knew something like that would happen. FF does do animations but is stuck with a bit simpler functionality (keyframes).

Comment: @wnajar - It's my opinion that editing someone else's answer to add your own commentary is a bit heavy-handed, especially extensive commentary. Beyond addressing *maybe* what is absolutely necessary to understand the answer enough for the context you've intended (meaning, clarification and this should also be rare), please refrain from treating the answers you receive as an extension of your question, and place those in the comments below the question, where it belongs. `:)`

Comment: I've seen it done both ways.

In either event, here's a jsFiddle of what I used: http://jsfiddle.net/vnLnH/16/

Comment: Thanks for deleting the additional and helpful commentary... you know it would have been helpful for other users. The whole point of creating the question was to be helpful for other people looking to do the same thing... womp womp

Comment: @wnajar - If you feel it should be reviewed by a moderator, flag the question for a moderators attention.

Comment: @JaredFarrish I did approve the edits, but I see what you mean.

Comment: @wnajar, I think it would be more suitable to put a short conclusion at the bottom of your question.

Comment: @grc - True; it's been so long since I got this or that permission, I forget you need certain rep to do this or that. My apologies if the deletion was heavy-handed on *my* part, I just didn't see what Cornell this or whatever had to do with answering the question; 90% of the text was noise.

Comment: If you had actually read it... one sentence was about Cornell and it had to do with the website that the solution was on, which could be used as a demo for future Googlers. The edit also included a quirk with the method that users might not have noticed and that nobody has written about here, and was helpful (namely weird things that would happen if you changed the text size or the gradient parameters). Now all that information is lost to heavy-handed moderation. Did you go to Penn or something? :( Sorry for irritating you man, I think everyone else would have thought it was helpful.

Answer (score 2):

First, I'd put spans around the individual arrows so that you can change their CSS settings individually:

```
<span class="glowquote"><span>&raquo;</span> <span>&raquo;</span> <span>&raquo;</span></span>
```

Then, assuming you're using [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/docs/animate) (because as far as I know core jQuery won't animate colours) you can do something like the following:

```
function doGlow(numTimes) {

    var $arrows = $("span.glowquote span");

    function nextGlow(i) {
        $arrows.eq(i).animate({
            color: "green"
        }, 400).animate({
            color: "black"
        }, 400, function() {
            i = (i + 1) % $arrows.length;
            if (i === 0) numTimes--;
            if (numTimes > 0) nextGlow(i);
        });
    }
    nextGlow(0);
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/KrL44/1

(Or here is the original version of my demo that just kept looping indefinitely: http://jsfiddle.net/KrL44/)

Comment: Good answer @nnnnnn, I thought somebody might try to do that method. I thought similar but wondered if I was just less experienced and there might be a better way.

I'm thinking that the limitation of using a loop-type method like you did in `nextGlow()` might limit us to that kindof jerky on-and-off animation that we see, no? Your answer obviously works but I'm going to leave the question open to see what the community can think of. 

Thanks for responding!

Comment: Obviously if nobody else comes up with a method then I'll mark yours as the correct answer, assuming there is no better way to do it.

Comment: Too late. I made a few changes so you could more easily see the effect: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/KrL44/2/

Comment: Thanks wnajar and @JaredFarrish. Meanwhile I was updating my original code to let you call `doGlow()` with a parameter telling it how many times to go through the left-to-right cycle.

Comment: @JaredFarrish I could see the effect before; I'm talking about the on-off /break/ on-off /break/ on-off thing that kinda kills it. I had this in mind before but it doesn't really give the desired effect of drawing the user's eye to the right, like a slide-to-unlock-ish. I guess my real question originally was if there was a clever way to imitate the animation, since anything I came up with seemed pretty hack-ish.

**Edit** to clarify what I meant about "jerky" I don't mean the actual animation (which is great) I mean the inability to have one glow in while the other glows out simultaneously

Comment: Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/KrL44/3/ - basically the same thing except the next element will start glowing in while the previous glows out.

Comment: @wnajar - I meant literally I couldn't hardly discern the (somewhat dark) green with the black; I didn't think it was working at first. Literally, it was just meant to "show" the effect more clearly. And I can see what you mean; you want a rolling effect, one to start as the last is partially finished, fade in/fade out.

Comment: @nnnnnn a bit better. I updated the original post again, I guess what I was looking for was something like this http://css-tricks.com/slide-to-unlock/. Very hack-ish and not really what I thought we could come up with but it has the animation down to a T.

Comment: I just think this is easier to see the intended effect: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/KrL44/5/

Comment: I guess I meant more of a "sliding" animation. I was trying to imitate this using transitions and iterative `color` changes but I'm wondering if there is a better way to imitate the "slide" without doing that. 

Just some food for thought. Thanks everyone for the responses, some good ideas on the table.

Comment: You can tweak the parameters of the `.animate()` methods, possibly add some calls to `.delay()` in the chain, break the animations into smaller pieces, further overlap the animations of the different elements - up to you to do that until you get something you're happy with, but I see no reason why you couldn't get what you want with JS if you're willing to experiment. If you add a few more arrows you could have several in various shades of green at once...

Comment: Nice, I was skeptical JS could handle it that well. @wnajar, take a look at that one. Now, if the spotlight effect could be applied around the lettering as well...

Comment: @nnnnnn That does look a bit better, at the downside of adding a somewhat silly amount of arrows. I really don't know which one to select as the right answer, and it's a shame StackOverflow doesn't allow multiple accepted answers because everyone is "right" here, just in different ways.

Comment: @wnajar - I think putting more than three arrows just helped show the effect better. Here's a fiddle with a `text-shadow` to help the illumination. Not quite the full spotlight, but useful. It also requires an add-on script to work on `text-shadow`. http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/KrL44/10/

Answer (score 1):

try this:

html:

```
<span class="glowquote"><span>&raquo;</span> <span>&raquo;</span> <span>&raquo;</span> </span>
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var i = 0;
    function run() {
        $('.glowquote span:eq('+ i +')').animate({color: 'green'}, 500, function(){
         $(this).animate({color: 'black'}, 500);
           i++;
           if (i > 2) { i = 0 } 
           run() 
        })
   }
 run()            
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wQ9AT/

Comment: This also works but has the same limitation as the solution above. The "on-off /break/ on-off /break/ on-off" kind of thing that makes it seem a bit hack-ish and not in the spirit of the animation.

Comment: BETTER! Still a bit of the same limitation. It's easier to see when you have the color fade in the background. Like here I've done it with white (http://jsfiddle.net/wQ9AT/1/), you did it with green. Obviously if you don't fade it into the background it will seem a bit off.

I wonder if this is just a limitation we will never overcome using Javascript or if there is a clever way to beat it.

Comment: @wnajar you can change the duration of the animation to get to the desired effect http://jsfiddle.net/wQ9AT/3/

Comment: I realize that and I think some other people have dialed it down a bit better. Your answer is still obviously "correct" and there is nothing wrong with it. I just made the question to see if we could come up with the most attractive way, as this might be a very popular effect.